# Ajax передает переменную, а файл ее не видит

Tags: php, ajax

Добрый день. Передаю ajax функцией в php файл две переменные.

```
function selectCategory(){
    var category_id = $('select[name="category_id"]').val();
    if(!category_id){
            $('div[name="selectCategory"]').html('');

    }else{
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax.base.php",
                    data: { action: 'showRegionForInsert', category_id:       category_id },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(responce){ $('div[name="selectCategory"]').html(responce); }
            });
    };
};
```

При этом переменная *action* обрабатывается и файл ее видит, а *category_id* нет.

Во вкладке *network* у php файла в *headers* в пункте *form data* написаны значения обеих переменных, но файл ее почему то не видит.
Вот php файл

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gz_database_main","root","");
$sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE status = "1" and parent IS NOT NULL and parent = :category_id';
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':category_id', intval($_POST['$category_id']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
// Получение и возврат результатов
$i = 0;
$categoryList = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $categoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $categoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $i++;
}
echo '<select name="pod_category_id" id="pod_category_id"  class="form-control">';
foreach ($categoryList as $listCateg) {
     echo '<option value="'.$listCateg['id'].'">'.$listCateg['name'].'</option>';
};
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что это такое?

```
intval($_POST['$category_id'])
```

Здесь по идее должно быть

```
intval($_POST['category_id'])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вот я протупила))